# Returning If-Else Result Independent of If-Else Order?

Tags: c#, if-statement

If I had the following code:

```
string x = "123";
string y = "abc";

if (stringVar.Contains(x))
{
    return x;
}
else if (stringVar.Contains(y))
{
    return y;
}
```

where

```
string stringVar = "123abc";
```

it would

```
return x;
```

However

```
stringVar = "abc123";
```

would also

```
return x;
```

Is there a way where instead of following the pre-defined order of the if-else statement, I could have the return result be based upon the order of stringVar instead?

My desired result is if:

```
stringVar = "123abc";
...
return x;
```

and if:

```
stringVar = "abc123";
...
return y;
```

EDIT:

This example is a very simplified example of my current problem, String.StartsWith() would not always work as the text I am looking for is not always at the start of stringVar. Additionally, in my actual problem there are no distinct separators between words (i.e. no spaces) either making it difficult to split stringVar.

Comment: `stringVar.StartsWith()`?

Comment: Look at the `StartsWith` method on the `string` class, that might help you. It would at least tell you which substring is first in your variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First i would suggest to store the items in a collection, for  example:

```
string[] words = {"123","abc"};
```

Now you can use `string.IndexOf` and LINQ:

```
return words
    .Where(stringVar.Contains)
    .OrderBy(stringVar.IndexOf)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a better answer then mine.

Comment: Why not just use StartsWith?

Comment: @CodeNotFound: because it must not starts with it, the substring can be at the end. But if there are multiple matches the first substring should be returned.

Comment: Nope the OP didn't say that. Look at the first use case he gave with "abc123" :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound: OP also used `Contains`

Comment: He used `Contains` because he didn't know about `StartsWith` I think.

Comment: Yes @CodeNotFound this example was simplified for the sake of readability; my actual problem does not always start with the text I am searching for. I have edited my original post with this information.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you for your answer, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @CodeNotFound: Nope. _"`String.StartsWith()` would not always work as the text I am looking for is not always at the start of `stringVar`"_ :)

Answer (score 1):

try `string.IndexOf()`. it returns the first index of a substring else, -1

then you can return based on which number is lower.

```
"abc123".indexOf("abc") = 0
"abc123".indexOf("123") = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Put search strings in an array, compute `IndexOf`, and pick the earliest match:

```
var searchStrings = new[] {"abc", "123"};
var res = searchStrings.Select(s => new { // Pair up a string with its index in stringVar
    Value = s
,   Index = stringVar.IndexOf(s)
})
.Where(p => p.Index >= 0)                 // Remove strings that did not produce a match
.OrderBy(p => p.Index)                    // Order by the match position
.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value);            // Pick the earliest one
```

Comment: Should be noted this is more efficient than Tim's answer since it only searches for each sub-string once.

Comment: @juharr That's right. In most realistic scenarios, though, it would make no measurable difference, because Tim's code goes for the second pass only on strings where the first pass has been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-Linq way to do it.

```
var subStrings = new[] {"abc", "123"};
string result = null;
int position = stringVar.Length;
foreach(var sub in subStrings)
{
    var currPos = stringVar.IndexOf(sub);
    if(currPos > -1 && currPos < position)
    {
        position = currPos;
        result = sub;
    }
}

return result;
```